# Why does Kyoko come to the city in Madoka Magica?

Tags: madoka-magica

Why does Kyoko come to the city in Madoka Magica?

There is probably a very simple answer for this, but I'm too lazy to go back and rewatch or to skim through a wiki.

Comment: You can probably split those questions into separate question posts.

Comment: @Frosteeze Probably, but it would be a bother to keep track of all these questions separately, lol

Comment: @Christian But actually, you should probably ask them as separate questions, since they're separate questions.

Comment: @Christian it actually makes for better organization. I know because I did the same thing as what you did here when I first started out. I regretted it ever since. ;)

Comment: I transcluded your latter two questions to http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/25728/ and http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/25726/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why does Kyoko come to the city?

We learn quite a bit about this in The Different Story, a sidestory manga that basically tells us about Kyouko and Mami prior to the events of the series (mostly before the point where Homura wakes up in the hospital, meaning that most of what we learn is timeline-agnostic).

There is an informal system among magical girls whereby each one has their own "territory", so to speak, within which they and they alone can hunt witches. This is because having multiple magical girls work together in a given area requires them to split the proceeds (the Grief Seeds) amongst each other, which nobody really wants to do.

Upon learning that Mami has perished, Kyouko ― who, until that point, had the neighboring city of Kazamino as her territory ― presumably saw this as a good opportunity for her to expand her range.

Comment: with the second last Paragraph, Moemura (the Homura who had braided hair) tried to tell the others about what witches really are however no one believed her, this is the same timeline Mami killed Kyoko. after terminating that timeline Homura realized she cant warn everyone because they wont believe her and decided to go solo